# Calculating Big O for nested loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having problems calculating Big O for the following code. Im never the smartest cookie.
Can someone kindly explain it. My guess here was O(N^2) due to the nested loops but I know there's more to it than that.

```
static inline int f1 (int a, int b)
{
 for (int c = 0; c < b; c++)
 {
   a -= n;
 }
 return a;
}

int f2 (int n) 
{
  int r = n * n * n;
  for (double i = n; i >= 0; i -= 2)
  {
     r = f1(r, i);
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: O((N/2)^2) is not a thing.  You remove/collapse constants when calculating O.

Comment: I don't think there is anything more to it than that. Calculating Big O notation is quite intuitive I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that f1's runtime purely depends on the second parameter, which controls the number of loop iterations.  Its runtime is therefore linear in the second parameter.

Next, notice that the loop in f2 runs n/2 times, with i taking on values 0, 2, 4, 6, ..., n.  Since i is the second parameter to f1, the runtime is given by

> 0 + 2+ 4+ ... + n
>
> = 2(0 + 1+ 2+ .. + n)
>
> = 2Θ(n^2)
>
> = Θ(n^2)

So the runtime is Θ(n^2).  Note that pretty much everything else is a distraction intended to mislead you.  Focusing purely on the variables that control the iteration and looping reveals the actual logic you need to focus on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 and the second to third line is done by realizing that 1+2+3+...+n is the ["small gauss"](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/jo1.html) (is that what you call it in english?) which boils down to 1+2+3+..+n being the same as `n*(n+1)/2` which scales proportionally to `n^2`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please try **to avoid** at all costs float/double as for-loop counters because they are inexact. Use size_t or any other int type. Furthermore as far as I can tell you from your code, your converting i from double to int anyway, so there is no need for that double there.
2. Your loops can be written like this:

   ```
   int r = n * n * n;
   for (double i = n; i >= 0; i -= 2)
   {
     for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
     {
       r -= n;
     }
   }
   ```

Outer loop: O(n/2) - it "jumps" 2 units at each steps => the number of operations is n/2

Inner loop: O(n/2) - technically, it iterates to i, but as i has the max value of n/2 and the inner loop is going up 1 by 1 => complexity is the same n/2

Whole complexity: O((n/2)^2)

**UPDATE**

As others suggested, yes you can collapse the constant part (in this case "/2"), but in my opinion it is more clear like I originally posted. Hope that helps too.

Answer (score 0):

You may, mathematically speaking, proceed formally like the following:

[image]

Where op is the number of constant time **op**erations executed in `f1()`.
I could have added `op'` or such for `f2()`, but that doesn't seem necessary.

To compute the number of operations, say T(10), just let `op = 1`.